# Django get_queryset return custom variables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-filter

Using users as an example I am trying to show how many users there are. `get_context_data` works totally fine but `get_queryset` does not. I know that it's not set up properly but I've been playing around with it for quite some days and something is just not clicking..

The main goal is to use the [Dajngo-Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) form and then be able to get the updated number of user count. I've only found endless documentation on how to show the "list" of users. Which I have done but no documentation on how to show custom variables. I have many statistics & charts I'd like to calculate based on the filters applied.

```
class UserFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = 'community/user_list.html'
    model =  User
    filterset_class = UserFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_count = User.objects.all().count()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserFilterView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['user_count'] = User.objects.all().count()
        return context
```

Comment: If you want to show aggregated stats and not model objects then you shouldn't use model based views. Or you could annotate the stats in the queryset

Comment: Which would be the best approach? Still have yet to find a solution. Currently trying to add a queryset: context['filter'] = UserFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context['user_count'] = User.objects.all().count()
```

is set to always count all users. So, of course, it's going to always do what it's programmed it to do.

Instead, I should use .count from the filtered queryset.

view.py

```
class UserFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = 'community/user_list.html'
    model =  User
    filterset_class = UserFilter

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserFilterView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['qs'] = User.objects.all()
        return context
```

template:

```
User Count: {{ filter.qs.count }}
```